# Retag [lambda] to [aws-lambda] where appropriate

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The [aws-lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-lambda) tag is for:

> AWS Lambda allows users to run code in response to events, while also managing the infrastructure necessary to execute the code within milliseconds of an event.

The [lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lambda) tag is for:

> Anonymous functions or closures in programming languages such as Lisp, C#, C++, Lua, Python, Ruby, Javascript or Java. (Also, lambda expression.)

Many askers use the [lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lambda) tag when they mean [aws-lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-lambda). I believe that at least 600 questions need to be re-tagged / un-tagged ([shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blambda%5D+aws+is%3Aq))

Comment: Your search was including questions and answers. There are about 600 if you only include questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blambda%5D+aws+is%3Aq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a good idea.

However, let us, as usual, make sure to not just retag the question, but fix all issues it has while we are at it.

Also, let's see if we can some 2k+ users with sufficient domain knowledge on board. <2k-suggesting that many tag-only edits is not efficient, especially considering how full that queue is these days.

Comment: Any chance you could take the lead on pushing this through? Is there any way I could help organize this?

Comment: @Jedi Hm, unfortunately, I don't know anything about aws-lambda myself, so I'd rather not mess around in those questions myself. I can try to find some people in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) tomorrow, or you can try yourself. It's not very busy at this hour though.